# How to include class library in Scala project?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm trying to incorporate a class that I extracted from another Scala project into a class library that I can reference from multiple projects. However, I cannot seem to reference the class from inside my client project.  I'm newish to IntelliJ 15.0.6 and my background in Scala is limited to scripts.

1. I extracted the class I need to a new Scala SBT project called "MyUtils"
2. I added a JAR artifact to the lib project & build it. It generated the designated JAR file artifact.
3. I created a new client Scala SBT project to consume the class called "MyApp"
4. I added a Scala library dependency on the JAR in the client IDE project settings,  selecting Classes as the type of files the JAR contains
5. I saved and rebuilt the project to refresh references.
6. I expanded the reference to my imported JAR in the project browser. It shows the following
   META-INF
   MyUtils (the class I need)
   If I double-click on the class I need inside the JAR, the IDE shows the source file for the class
7. I added an import statement for the class I want from the JAR, but the IDE cannot resolve it.
8. I added a line of code to create an instance of the new class, thinking the IDE tools might offer me a way to fix the issue, but it actually seemed to resolve the class. (The line isn't red and it doesn't show an error icon.) However, if I make/rebuild, I get a compiler error stating that the class type was not found. It seems like the IDE sees the class but not the compiler.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the JAR reference problem by creating src/main/scala/lib and copying the JAR to that folder.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SBT, I would suggest you to use it to manage you library dependencies. SBT is a build tool which will download the jar file and make it available in your project for you.

To add a library dependency (in this case apache derby) add the following line towards the end of your "build.sbt" file

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.derby" % "derby" % "10.4.1.3"
```

You can find your dependency on this site - https://mvnrepository.com/. Search for your library name, choose a version and copy the script from the sbt tab.

Comment: The JAR is a local file, not in a maven repository.